# User deletes his own question after getting an answer

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, deleted-posts

I answered a question today on a site (*[How can I count "\n\n" in a string with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58050217/how-can-i-count-n-n-in-a-string-with-python)*) and two minutes after I answered the question, the author thanked users in the comments and deleted his question.

1. This hides the answer from other users that might have the same problem (a not so uncommon rookie mistake in Python)
2. It feels quite frustrating to see my answer vanish after it might have helped the question author.

Undeleting an answer to a deleted question is impossible, as is voting or commenting the question.

What is the right way to react to this?

Comment: You should post this on SO meta https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ Depending on how they deal with this kind of thing, a mod could undelete the question.

Comment: _"What ist the right way to react to this?"_ Move on.

Comment: @MarkKirby Sorry, i didn't realize i switched into meta.stackexchange instead of meta.stackoverflow. Thanks for your suggestion. I just realized that flagging a post for moderator attention still works on deleted questions, so I'll try that first before opening another meta post

Comment: MSO duplicates https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316117/what-to-do-when-a-question-you-answered-gets-deleted-intentionally and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355059/op-deleted-question-after-getting-a-satisfactory-answer

Comment: @cg909 _"I just realized that flagging a post for moderator attention still works ..."_ Don't do that please, your flag will most probably be declined. There's no need for flagging.

Comment: There very much is. This is defnitely destructive behaviour and the moderators ought to be notified about it.

Answer (score 4):

Move on.

There are more important things to focus on in life. If the user keeps doing this, they will get Question Banned soon enough - that's one of the reasons we *have* it - to stop those who waste others' time.